# Embedding other system and overriding it links

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question. Is there is a way to override hrefs, posts and etc? In example I embed 3rd part forum inside of my  container and I click anything there page response will be loaded into the same container and not reloading everything in the window.

Comment: You mean like a phishing website?

Comment: @codeka: This doesn't have to be nefarious. There are all sorts of valid, aboveboard reasons he may want to do this. This is the classic dilemma of technology: Technology is neutral, it can be used for Good, and for Evil.

Comment: @codeka: No not as phishing. I use if for my own site to embed forum inside of it. I want open source forum which is btw on my server side so I am not trying to do something criminal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are two ways you can do this:

1. Using an `iframe`. `iframe`s are independent windows embedded within the window, and so navigation within the `iframe` stays within the `iframe`. So load the 3rd party forum there. This will be the easiest and most compatible way.
2. (This is rather more complicated.) After page load, you can hook the `click` event on links and the `submit` event on forms with client-side Javascript. When the user clicks a link, cancel the click event and use Ajax to load the HTML for the link and then insert it into your page at the appropriate location. Similarly, when the user clicks the submit button of a form, use the event to gather the form information and send the POST via Ajax instead (cancelling the submit event), then process the response. Note that in both cases (clicking links and posting forms), the browser navigation buttons will not do what the user expects unless you also integrate a history management library into your site, which further increases complexity.

Answer (score 0):

with [iQuery](http://jquery.com/) you can have something like this

```
$('a').click(function(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open(this.href);

}
```

Comment: He didn't ask how to turn the links into popups/new windows!